# Getting pictures from a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, extract

I have a large PDF document containing many pictures and text.  Is there a way to extract the pictures from this PDF document programatically?

Comment: Any specific platform and/or programming language?

Comment: The answer to this question is: "yes" - you might want to add some more details to your question.

Comment: I guess im most comfortable with Java, but im willing to use any other tool or programming language to solve this.

Comment: FYI, not sure if you *want* to do this programatically, but there are plenty of tools that already do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache's [ExtractImages](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.html) class.

Use:

```
 java org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractImages <pdffile> <password> [imageprefix]
```

Comment: Link broken, try this one https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#extractimages